# Differential Equation Differentiation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, implicit-differentiation

Given $y(x)$ and $x=\sin\theta$, how would you differentiate the following equation w.r.t $x$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = (\sec\theta) \frac{dy}{d\theta}$$

I've tried to differentiate using the product rule but one of the terms is:

$$\sec\theta\frac{d}{dx}\left\{\frac{dy}{d\theta}\right\}$$

I'm not sure how to deal with this term to obtain an equation in terms of $y$ and $\theta$. Thanks.

Comment: Your expression $\dfrac{d}{dx}\left\{\dfrac{dy}{d\theta}\right\}\sec\theta$ could be considered ambiguous. Does it mean $\dfrac{d}{dx}\left\{\dfrac{dy}{d\theta}\, \sec\theta \right\}$ or $\left\{ \dfrac{d}{dx} \dfrac{dy}{d\theta}\right\}\sec\theta \text{ ?}$ Your broader context suggests that you mean the former, but why bother with delimiters like $\left\{ \phantom {\dfrac d {mm}} \right\} \vphantom{\displaystyle\int\limits^A}{}$ if not for the purpose of being explicit about that? $\qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = (\sec\theta) \frac{dy}{d\theta}$$
do you mean this ?
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} =\frac d {dx}\left( (\sec\theta) \frac{dy}{d\theta} \right )$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} =\frac d {d \theta}\left( (\sec\theta) \frac{dy}{d\theta} \right ) \frac {d \theta}{dx}$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} =\left( (\sec\theta) \frac{d^2y}{d\theta^2} + \frac{dy}{d\theta}\frac d {d \theta} \sec \theta\right ) \frac {d \theta}{dx}$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} =\left( (\sec\theta) \frac{d^2y}{d\theta^2} + \frac{dy}{d\theta}\frac d {d \theta} \sec \theta\right ) \sec \theta$$

And 
$$\frac d {d \theta} \sec \theta=\frac {\sin \theta}{\cos^2 \theta}$$
So that we finally have
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} =\left( \frac{d^2y}
{d\theta^2} + \tan \theta\frac{dy}{d\theta} \right ) \sec^2 \theta$$